# Regular Expression: Any character that is not a letter or number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that will match any character that is not a letter or a number. Once found I want to replace it with a blank space.

Answer (score 211):

To match anything other than letter or number you could try this:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

And to replace:

```
var str = 'dfj,dsf7lfsd .sdklfj';
str = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, ' ');
```

Comment: `\w` is for Word characters and is exactly the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (notice that underscore is considered a word character.) ...so the shorthand would be `str.replace(/[^\w]/g, ' ')`

Comment: but it will include many unicode letters, too! is there any way to exclude unicode letters?

Comment: To include unicode characters, you can use [^\p{L}0-9]

Comment: @Dave: As of 2018 you can't without a polyfill, apparently... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes

Comment: is there a way, instead of repalce with a space... replace with "\" followed by the character that was been identified?  Like this: 
make this dfj,dsf7lfsd .sdklfj into this dfj\,dsf7lfsd \.sdklfj?

Answer (score 62):

This regular expression matches anything that isn't a letter, digit, or an underscore (`_`) character.

```
\W
```

For example in JavaScript:

```
"(,,@,£,() asdf 345345".replace(/\W/g, ' '); // Output: "          asdf 345345"
```

Comment: I believe he is looking for /(_|\W)/g, to match anything not a digit or letter (english language)

Comment: @sbmaxx I want to replace all except &, (, ) these characters. how could i add this condition in the current regex.

Answer (score 18):

You are looking for:

```
var yourVar = '1324567890abc§$)%';
yourVar = yourVar.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ' ');
```

This replaces all non-alphanumeric characters with a space.

The "g" on the end replaces all occurrences.

Instead of specifying a-z (lowercase) and A-Z  (uppercase) you can also use the in-case-sensitive option: `/[^a-z0-9]/gi`.

Comment: Will it match spaces aswell? I need spaces to be kept. Thanks.

Comment: Space characters would match, but then would be replaced by space characters, so in effect it would leave them alone (a space will stay a space).

Answer (score 16):

- Match letters only `/[A-Z]/ig`
- Match anything not letters `/[^A-Z]/ig`
- Match number only `/[0-9]/g` or `/\d+/g`
- Match anything not number `/[^0-9]/g` or `/\D+/g`
- Match anything not number or letter `/[^A-Z0-9]/ig`

There are other possible patterns

Answer (score 14):

This is way way too late, but since there is no accepted answer I'd like to provide what I think is the simplest one: \D - matches all non digit characters.

```js
var x = "123 235-25%";
x.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Results in x: "12323525"

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 5):

Just for others to see:

```
someString.replaceAll("([^\\p{L}\\p{N}])", " ");
```

will remove any non-letter and non-number unicode characters.

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

Comment: I'm not sure where the two upvotes came from, but in JavaScript (which this question is about) there's no `replaceAll`, and the `\p{..}` property escapes are not widely implemented.

Comment: @Nickolay There is now! :)

Answer (score 5):

try doing str.replace(/[^\w]/);
It will replace all the non-alphabets and numbers from your string!

Edit 1: `str.replace(/[^\w]/g, ' ')`

Comment: A working answer would be `str.replace(/[^\w]/g, ' ')`. If you don't include `/g` flag it will only replace the first occurence. And if you don't define a replacement string, here a blank space `' '`, it will replace by `undefined` all over the place. Finally, underscores will not be replaced because they match `\w`. This answer is not a perfect fit.

Answer (score 4):

To match anything other than letter or number or letter with diacritics like `é` you could try this:

```
[^\wÀ-úÀ-ÿ]
```

And to replace:

```
var str = 'dfj,dsf7é@lfsd .sdklfàj1';
str = str.replace(/[^\wÀ-úÀ-ÿ]/g, '_');
```

Inspired by the top post with support for diacritics

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900132/1248177)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `str = str.replace(/\W|_/g,'');` it will return a string without any character and you can specify if any especial character after the pipe bar `|` to catch them as well.

`var str = "1324567890abc§$)% John Doe #$@'.replace(/\W|_/g, '');` it will return `str = 1324567890abcJohnDoe`

or look for digits and letters and replace them for empty string (""):

`var str = "1324567890abc§$)% John Doe #$@".replace(/\w|_/g, '');` it will return `str = '§$)%   #$@';`

Answer (score 0):

Working with unicode, best for me:

```
text.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/gu, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

To match anything other than letter or number you could try this:

```py
import re

regular_expression = r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]'  
new_string = re.sub(regular_expression, '', old_string)
```

re substring is an alternative to the replace command but the key here is the regular expression.

The ^ means *italic* NOT ONE of the character contained between the brackets.

The /s _italic_means ANY ONE space/non-space character.

I recommend this web which explains regular expressions arguments: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html

Comment: You might want to add some context to your answer, what is this code doing?

Comment: Hope its a better answer now :)